# Zero Padding of FFT

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft

There are many question related to the zero padding a time domain signal to get more frequency bins after performing Fourier transform. As I understand this process is equivalent to trigonometric interpolation in the frequency domain. However, I am not certain of this fact. Can anyone verify this correct or incorrect mathematically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's true that zero-padding in the time domain corresponds to interpolation in the frequency domain. If you have a length $N$ signal $x[n]$, its discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is given by

$$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j2\pi nk/N}\tag{1}$$

The signal $x[n]$ can be expressed in terms of its DFT coefficients $X[k]$ by the inverse DFT

$$x[n]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X[k]e^{j2\pi nk/N}\tag{2}$$

Since the coefficients $X[k]$ contain the same information as the signal $x[n]$, anything that can be computed from $x[n]$ can also be computed from $X[k]$.

Let $\tilde{X}(\omega)$ denote the discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT) of $x[n]$:

$$\tilde{X}(\omega)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-jn\omega}\tag{3}$$

Note that $\omega$ is a continuous variable. Comparing (1) and (3) shows that the DFT is simply a sampled version of the DTFT:

$$X[k]=\tilde{X}(2\pi k/N),\quad k=0,\ldots,N-1\tag{4}$$

Furthermore, a length $L$ DFT ($L>N$) of $x[n]$ simply corresponds to a more densely sampled version of $\tilde{X}(\omega)$:

$$X_L[l]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j2\pi nl/L}=\tilde{X}(2\pi l/L),\quad l=0,\ldots,L-1\tag{5}$$

Now let's express $\tilde{X}(\omega)$ in terms of the length $N$ DFT of $x[n]$. Rewriting (3) using (2) gives

$$\begin{align}\tilde{X}(\omega)&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X[k]e^{j2\pi nk/N}e^{-jn\omega}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X[k]\underbrace{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-jn(\omega-2\pi k/N)}}_{G(\omega-2\pi k/N)}
\end{align}\tag{6}$$

where $G(\omega)$ is an interpolation function which can be expressed by

$$G(\omega)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-jn\omega}=\frac{e^{-j\omega(N-1)/2}}{N}\frac{\sin(N\omega/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}\tag{7}$$

By setting $\omega=2\pi l/L$ in (6) and using (5) you can see that the length $L$ zero-padded DFT of $x[n]$ can be computed from the length $N$ DFT using the interpolation function given by (7):

$$X_L(l)=\tilde{X}(2\pi l/L)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X[k]G(2\pi l/L-2\pi k/N)\tag{8}$$

Comment: Can we think that zero padding (from length N to L)  is equivalent to considering the time signal is made up of L number of sinusoidal instead of N? L>N

Comment: @Creator: By the inverse DFT formula the zero-padded signal can be represented by a sum of $L$ complex exponentials. But they add up such that the last $L-N$ values are zero, so the non-zero values of $x[n]$ can be represented by a sum of only $N$ complex exponentials.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can we say anything about G, the interpolate function  for example :It is the minimum entropy solution or minimum energy solution or something else? I am looking for a condition under which it is optimal or is derived from?

Comment: @Creator: Note that $G(\omega)$ is not the result of any optimization process. It is just the interpolation function that is implicitly used when computing the DFT of a zero-padded signal. In that sense it is not helpful to think of it in terms of optimality criteria.

Comment: My interest is to replace the function G by some other means. Specifically, under the known condition that number of sinusoidal present in the signal is less than N, so obviously far less that L.   Do you have any suggestions? Is there anything in the literature?

Comment: @Creator: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Why would you want to replace $G$? The most efficient way to interpolate is to do IFFT -> zero pad -> FFT, so you normally wouldn't use $G$ or any other function in practice.

Comment: I only need the spectrum, not the time domain signal. The frequency resolution after zero padding is very poor. I am looking for a way to improve.

Comment: @Creator: If you mean by "frequency resolution" the ability to resolve closely spaced sinusoidal components, then interpolation will not help. Frequency resolution can only improved by having a longer time domain block, i.e. more data. If you just want more frequency points then the approach IFFT -> zero padding -> FFT is still much more efficient than anything else, regardless whether you need a time domain signal or not.

Comment: May I ask  what is the limitation? Why two closely spaced sinusoidal components, cannot be resolved with interpolation? Why can't we use  some other structure from the signal?

Comment: @Creator: The limitation is in the number of time domain data points. Zero padding doesn't increase the amount of information which would be necessary to increase resolution. Frequency resolution increases with (time domain) window length; for a fixed window length resolution is fixed; zero-padding just gives you a denser sampling of an already smeared out frequency response function.

Comment: Can someone explain the right side of Eq (7)? Not sure where Eq 7 came from.

Comment: @EduardoReis: Just a geometric series.

Comment: @MattL. Would you be able to take a look on this question?