# Interpolate DFT Coefficient of a Frequency That Is Not in the DFT Bin

Tags: fft, dft, interpolation

I'm using the Jacobsen interpolation to get a more precise frequency of my signal. To get the corresponding DFT coefficient I'm doing:

$$X_{f} = \sum_{n=0}^{N}{x_{n}  e^{-2\pi ifn}}$$

Where $x_{n}$ is the samples of my signal and $f$ is the frequency found by the interpolation (that is not one of those in the DFT bins).
This is a quite heavy computation for large signals.

Is there a method to interpolate the coefficient corresponding to that frequency without having to compute the sum?

Comment: Have look at [Goertzel](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/495.php) based solution.

Comment: But the Goertzel solution also requires looping throw the samples, I was looking more for an interpolation method using the closest DFT bins.

Comment: [This answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24426/4298) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need very specific frequency you should either use the [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DFT) definition or the [Goertzel Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm).

Yet, if you need higher resolution Grid, you can use many off the shelf algorithms to interpolate.
The native Interpolation Kernel would be the [Dirichlet Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) since it is the Sampling Kernel for the DFT.
An easy way to interpolate the grid in the Frequency Domain using the Dirichlet Kernel is by [Zero Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Sampling_the_DTFT) of the signal in the Time Domain.
As this is equivalent of higher rate sampling of the [Discrete Time Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DTFT).

Answer (score 1):

Windowed Sinc interpolation works in the frequency domain as well as in the time domain for waveform reconstruction.