# DTFT reconstruction

Tags: sampling, interpolation, aliasing, dtft

I have a sampled DTFT. If we assume that there isn't aliasing in time domain, what is the best way to reconstruct DTFT from its equidistant samples? I though about Dirichlet interpolation. Do you know if there are other ways to do it? There is any difference between a theoretical approach and a practical approach?

Comment: [This answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24426/4298) (especially Eq. (6)) should answer your question.

Comment: Thank you! I read all the theory about it, but I've found a question that confused me. As I write above, the differences between a theoretical approach and a practical approach to the DTFT reconstruction. I think that the theoretical one, is the Dirichlet interpolation; the second one could be IFFT-> zero-padding -> FFT with a high sample density? That should be useful to see a quasi-continuous spectrum?

Comment: Yes, the second approach is practical if you're OK with a finite and equidistant set of points. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finite length time domain signals, the DTFT can be obtained from the DFT via interpolation, as explained in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24426/4298). In this case the DTFT can be evaluated at any desired frequency point because it is expressed as a function of a continuous frequency variable.

If a finite set of points is sufficient, it is much more efficient to apply an inverse DFT (using an FFT algorithm), then zero-pad the time-domain data, and apply a DFT (again, using an FFT algorithm). This will give you an equidistantly sampled DTFT with a sample density determined by the DFT length.